# How do you make objects dissapear in a specific time?

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm using libgdx to make a simple game where the characther collects coins to get scores, and I want to make it so that the coins only appears for like 1-2 seconds before dissapearing again. I'm not sure how to do that. I've tried a couple of techniques like a scheduler or nanoTime(), but I just can't get it to work.

I'm using an iterator to spawn in the coins. (this is in an update method)

```
if(TimeUtils.nanoTime() - coin.lastDropTime > 2000000000){
            coin.spawnCoin();
    }

    Iterator<Rectangle> iter = coin.coins.iterator();
    while(iter.hasNext()) {
        Rectangle gold_coin = iter.next(); 
        if(snail.bounds.overlaps(gold_coin)){
            score += 10;
            iter.remove();
        }
    }
```

This is the coin class.

```
public class Coin {

Sprite image;

boolean isVisible = true;

public Array<Rectangle> coins;
public long lastDropTime;

public Coin(){
    image = GameScreen.coin_sprite;
    coins = new Array<Rectangle>();
}

public void spawnCoin(){
    Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle();
    bounds.x = MathUtils.random(20, 1920 - 16);
    bounds.y = MathUtils.random(20, 1080 - 50);
    bounds.width = image.getWidth();
    bounds.height = image.getHeight();
    coins.add(bounds);
    lastDropTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
}

}
```

I can only get the coins to spawn 2 seconds after eachother, and the only way to get the coins removed is by letting the charachter overlap them.

Comment: Is your coin class supposed to be representative of a single coin or all the coins? You only have one lastDropTime for the all the coins and it sounds like you want a time for each coin. If you create a class for each individual coin with a lastDropTime, when you loop through your coins you can remove coins that have exceeded the time limit

Comment: well, I want the coins to spawn until you hit a bad coin or somethin that makes you lose and ends the game. Making a class for every coin doesn't seem to be the right thing to do.

Comment: By create a class for each individual coin, I mean create 1 class that represents a single coin with time created and have a list of instances of this class as your current coins

Comment: ah, now I see what you mean. Yeah I could try that and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply add a timer to your coins.

Currently you have a class `Coin` which should represent a coin. But you are holding al your coins there. The power of OOP programming is to abstract coin. See a Coin as it's own object and thus create a class only for this shiny little object.

```
public class Coin {

    //Fields specific for the coin
    private Vector2 position;
    private int worth;
    private Sprite sprite;

    //Fields for the timer, since this coin dissapears it should hold it's own self destruct timer
    public float timeAlive = 0;
    public float despawnTime = 2;

    public Coin(Vector2 position, int worth, Sprite sprite, float despawnTime) {
        this.position = position;
        this.worth = worth;
        this.sprite = sprite;
        this.despawnTime = despawnTime;
    }

    //Since we hold a list somewhere else of the objects represented by this class we should be able to delete them from the list when the time is up.
    public boolean isAlive()
    {
        return timeAlive < despawnTime;
    }

    //I like to abstract update and draw from render. In update we put the logic, which in this case is updating it's time alive.
    public void update()
    {
        timeAlive += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    }

    public void draw(SpriteBatch batch)
    {


        //Draw your object
    }
}

public class SomethingHoldingCoins {

    //A list to hold our coins
    List<Coin> coins = new ArrayList<Coin>();

    //A timer system to spawn coins
    private int spawnTime = 4;
    private int timer = 0;

    public void update()
    {
        //Increment timer by the time since last frame
        timer += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

        //check if timer past the spawn time
        if (timer >= spawnTime)
        {
            //Add a coin to the list
            coins.add(new Coin(somePosition, 100, coinSprite, 2));
            //subtract spawntime from timer
            timer -= spawnTime;
        }

        //iterate over the list of coins to do stuff like drawing and removing despawned coins

        for (Iterator<Coin> iterator = coins.iterator(); iterator.hasNext())
        {
            Coin coin = iterator.next();
            //Update the coin
            coin.update();
            //Check if it is still alive
            if (!coin.isAlive())
            {
                //remove the coin from the list since it is despawned anyway, then continue with the next iteration
                iterator.remove();
                continue;
            }

            coin.draw(spriteBatch);
        }
    }
}
```

The moment we create a coin by doing `new Coin(...)` we spawn it and the timer will run as long as we keep calling `update()` on it each frame. So in the object that is holding the coins we create a list, spawn them, update them, etc. Perhaps your map is a good place to put the coins, at least for `Mario` it is since a map holds `coins`.

Think about everything as objects. Like I put the worth value inside coin since a coin might have a value. It still depends on what you are trying to do and how big and (un)readable your classes are getting. A `Car` class for a simple driving game should probably hold it's `Wheels` inside it. But a much more advanced game might put the `Chassis` in the car and the `Chassis` would get a `Suspension` and the Suspension would finally get the `Wheels`. So each of them can hold there own functionality. This makes your code much more readable because of human logic and much smaller classes.

Comment: I do agree though this is a better solution if Coin be extended/altered, and even if not you could map spawn time to coin.

Comment: @heisbrandon I pretty much show him because he has that `Coin` class but he does not use it like a coin. It's such a small class and already getting a mess with that array of rectangles. The coin should simply be abstracted, give it it's own rectangle, position, value, etc and timer functionality. Readability is everything.

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked at ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor?

It has a method [scheduleWithFixedDelay](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html#scheduleWithFixedDelay(java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) which I think would accomplish what you need to do.

You would have to be careful though, as iterator's remove could throw a ConcurrentModificationException if you're iterating while a separate thread is removing items from the list, and at best that behavior is undefined. But if you're pursuing a threaded solution like this, you could have a separate thread checking for overlap.

Also, I apologize I'm not familiar with the Array interface, but I assume there is some method for removing any arbitrarily indexed object.

```
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new CoinRemover(coin, coins), 0, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

class CoinRemover implements Runnable {
    Coin coin;
    List<Coin> coins;

    public CoinRemover(Coin coin, List<Coin> coins) {
        this.coin = coin;
        this.coins = coins;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        coins.remove(coin);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think I've seen that before. Imma look into that, thanks!

Comment: @AntonHolm Don't use threads when you don't need too. He is most likely changing the state of coin and when that happens on a separate thread shit can hit the fan.

Comment: @menno-gouw I agree that if you are reading/writing values for the coins in separate threads then you should at least ensure the objects are thread safe. However if you're simply altering a collection in a separate thread, the state of those objects and their mutability are irrelevant.